# Temporarily Hide Div then Show Div when User starts Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

How can I temporarily hide a div *(.header-small)* then show it when the user starts scrolling the website?

here's an example of what i'm trying to achieve. The header totally drops down when the users start to scroll. how am i gonna do that?

http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/

Here's an example fiddle of my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="header-small">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {height:10000px;}
.header {background:black; width:100%; height:65px; position:relative;}
.header-small {background:black; width:100%; height:35px; position:fixed; top:0; display:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bendaggers/6wbpC/

Answer (score 3):

I would add a bit more logic like when to show the fixed menu when it passes the main one and hide it when you half way up the main. Also hide the small menu with css.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sC537/)

```
var headerSmall = $('.header-small');
var header = $('.header');
var whenToHide = (header.offset().top + header.height()) / 2;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var offset = headerSmall.offset();

    if (offset.top <= whenToHide) {
        headerSmall.slideUp();
    } else {
        headerSmall.slideDown();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.header-small').hide();
   $(window).scroll(function () {
   if($(window).scrollTop()>0){
    $('.header-small').show();
    }
    else{$('.header-small').hide();}    
   });
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wbpC/2/)

Comment: Hi sanki, can you add a slide down effect in your jquery?

Comment: @KareenLagasca: Checkout Satpal's last comment, he had already done that.